Python API: How to load an image and assign it to a texture in Blender 4.3?
In previous Blender versions, loading an image from a filepath then assigning to a texture was simple:
tex.image = bpy.data.images.load(filepath)
But now due to the new brush system, local images in the current blend file cannot be assigned to a texture. So this no longer works and I cannot figure out an alternative.
Does anyone have a solution? Thanks.
